# Spring Boot : Getting Null inputs from Form Submission

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, web

I have a basic form submission spring boot application.
My problem is when I am submitting the form I am getting null results.

Here is my form code :

```
<form method="post" action="#" th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${info}" commandName ="info">

              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{_FirstName}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{_LastName}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
              </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Select Country</label><br>
                    <select class="form-control" th:field="*{_Country}">
                      <option value="United State">United State</option>
                      <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
                      <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
                      <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
                      <option value="India">India</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
                 <label for="date">Date</label>
                 <input th:field="*{_Date}" class="form-control" type="date" value="2011-08-19" />
              </div>
              <div class="pull-right">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </div>

            </form>
```

In my controller I have url /form for get method and /save for post method
after getting result I am trying to log the inputs.
I am not sure am I populating a model through those inputs here ? if so why inputs are showing null.
My Controller Code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(Info info) {
    //model.addAttribute("info", new Info());
    return "form";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@Valid Info info, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "form";
    }
    model.addAttribute("_FirstName", info.get_FirstName());
    model.addAttribute("_LastName", info.get_LastName());
    model.addAttribute("_Country", info.get_Country());
    model.addAttribute("_Date", info.get_Date());


    String submitted = String.format("User Submission: firstname = %s, lastname = %s, country = %s, date = %s", 
            info.get_FirstName(), info.get_LastName(), info.get_Country(), info.get_Date());
    log.info(submitted);

    return "cv";
}
```

And My Model Code :

```
public class Info {

private String _FirstName;
private String _LastName;
private String _Country;
private Date _Date;

public Info() {

}

public Info(String _FirstName, String _LastName, String _Country, Date _Date) {
    super();
    this._FirstName = _FirstName;
    this._LastName = _LastName;
    this._Country = _Country;
    this._Date = _Date;
}

public String get_FirstName() {
    return _FirstName;
}
public void set_FirstName(String _FirstName) {
    this._FirstName = _FirstName;
}
public String get_LastName() {
    return _LastName;
}
public void set_LastName(String _LastName) {
    this._LastName = _LastName;
}
public String get_Country() {
    return _Country;
}
public void set_Country(String _Country) {
    this._Country = _Country;
}
public Date get_Date() {
    return _Date;
}
public void set_Date(Date _Date) {
    this._Date = _Date;
}


}
```

Can anyone please check what I am missing ?
I am getting in console :

```
User Submission: firstname = null, lastname = null, country = null, date = null
```

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Have you tested adding @ ModelAttribute before your @ Valid annotation as that: ? public String save(@ModelAttribute @Valid Info info, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

Comment: @Melardev Yes not working !

Comment: It worked for me when I changed from _FirstName to firstName, obviously youhave toc hange the setters as well, as well as the form html file

Comment: can you elaborate please ? 
th:field="*{_LastName}" < this should be th:field="*{lastName}" 
or the setter name for storing last name ?

Comment: I have written an answer below, let me know if it works, I have your code working, if you need it I write it completely...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code working in my environment, I will just show you the changes I made:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Info info, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("info", info);
        return "myform";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("info") Info info, HttpServletRequest request, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "myform";
        }
```

Please note that HttpServletRequest It is not needed, I added it so I can see if Spring was able to get the params with request.getParameterNames(), that proved to me that it did , it was something wrong with your code not with the binding ...

```
private String firstName;
    private String _LastName;
    private String _Country;
    private Date _Date;
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String set_LastName() {
        return _LastName;
    }
```

Interestingly the only setter called is setFirstName(), the others with name unchanged were not working ... so the problem is on naming.

html file

```
    <div class="form-group row">

        <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name">
```

Comment: This works now ! but I am confused, what was the problem with naming ?

Comment: @RayD'vard I don't know exactly, but as a genral rule of thumb me at least I try not to have variables/fields beginning with underscores, you may end up with problems in a lot of programming language or frameworks. Not too far away if I am not wrong, Spring Data will also misbehave if you use fields beginning with underscore. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions a couple of paragraphs below you can read "As we treat underscore as a reserved character we ..."

Comment: Thanks for the information ! I will keep it in mind and also in list for further research.

Answer (score 0):

Update your GET request method to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(Info info, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("info", new Info());
    return "form";
}
```

You need to provide Info object to your form to get it back. Also put `@ModelAttribute` in your POST method before/after `@Valid`